# Create a pivot table where the resulting columns are the product of the original columns and rows?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

This might be impossible to do without a ton of expensive scripting, but I would like to run it by the experts in case I'm missing something. It's hard to explain (because it's nonsensical.. i.e. not my choice), so I'll just give a very simplified example.

My source data sheet is like this...

```
+----------+-------+------+--------+
|     Date | Time  | Cars | Trucks |
+----------+-------+------+--------+
| 01/01/19 | 08:00 | 2    | 12     |
| 01/01/19 | 12:00 | 4    | 10     |
| 01/01/19 | 20:00 | 6    | 8      |
| 01/02/19 | 08:00 | 8    | 6      |
| 01/02/19 | 12:00 | 10   | 4      |
| 01/02/19 | 20:00 | 12   | 2      |
+----------+-------+------+--------+
```

.. and I want to have another sheet dynamically display it like ...

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|          | 08:00         | 12:00         | 20:00         |
+----------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
|          | Cars | Trucks | Cars | Trucks | Cars | Trucks |
+----------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| 01/01/19 | 2    | 12     | 4    | 10     | 6    | 8      |
| 01/02/19 | 8    | 6      | 10   | 4      | 12   | 2      |
+----------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
```

In other words, a column for each time at category combined.
Keep in mind that, in reality, this is a large data set. Also, I have a little bit of flexibility in the headers in the sense that, the two header rows in the output could be one. Something like "Cars 8:00", "Trucks 8:00", "Cars 12:00"... etc

Does anybody know how this could be done with a pivot table? Or some other simple'ish method?

Here's a live version of the same example...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1npQikx3Zwa2QZwDAk8IxyawYw2hkeYpPe9Nh4ImkZAE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: shouldn't be the C3 cell 12 instead of 2?

Comment: Sorry about that. Good catch. I'll fix it all up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 QUERY({Source!A2:B, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Source!C2:D),,999^99))}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "limit 0", 1)),,999^99)), " "), "1899-12-30", ), "hh:mm"), ""}; {"", 
 SPLIT(REPT(Source!C1&" "&Source!D1&" ", COUNTUNIQUE(Source!B2:B)), " ")}; 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({Source!A2:B, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Source!C2:D),,999^99))}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0))&" ",,999^99)), " ", 1, 0)), "where "&JOIN(" or ", "Col"&
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(Source!A2:A)))&" is not null"), 0))})
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16qRwASYXE0HgKtxx5H2_BOm7CTtYAZ3Df9NdBZ26FyY/copy)

Comment: Wow! OK, so it wasn't simple... but definitely got the job done. Thanks :)